# Can't select checkbox table Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm currently learning ReactJs and using Ant Design as a UI library. I have some problems when I tried to use the Selection (Checkbox Table). At first, it's fine with some basic interaction, I can get the selectedRowKeys, the selectedRow data normally to interact with the database. But when I need the Table to check some rows according to the data, it got some problems. When I set the props selectedRowKeys with data, it selects the right checkbox I want but I can't uncheck or select another checkbox. It shows the error:
[image]
**Uncaught TypeError: clone.push is not a function at arrAdd ...**
[image]
Here's how I'm doing it:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Radio, Divider } from 'antd';
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>,
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
  },
];
const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Jack',
    age: 20,
    address: 'Somewhere else',
  },
]; // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection

const rowSelection = {
  onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
    console.log(`selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`, 'selectedRows: ', selectedRows);
  },
  getCheckboxProps: (record) => ({
    name: record.name,
  }),
};

const Demo = () => {
  const dataKeys = "1,2"; //after handling data from server, I got a string like this which I can pass to Table
  return (
    <div>

      <Table
        rowSelection={{
          selectedRowKeys: dataKeys,
          type: selectionType,
          ...rowSelection,
        }}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

Comment: Can you show us the full error message ?

Comment: I have just updated the image of error above

Comment: and then show the declaration of `arrAdd`

Comment: I think it's one of the built-in function Ant Design provide. The error happens when I add selectedRowKeys to rowSelection in Table, else it work normally, but that's not I aim for. I'll update the arrAdd function above.

Comment: Pay a attention to your code  : ` const dataKeys = "1,2"; //after handling data from server, I got a string like this which I can pass to Table` , as the docs say , the `selectedRowKeys ` is a  array of string or number , your dataKey is the type of string , you should change it at first

Comment: That error is no longer shows, but when I click the checkbox, it didn't get checked or uncheck already checked boxes, and the selectedRowKeys: dataKeys can only track one more (like 4 checkboxes, it can't get all four, but only the two I set and one of another).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240162/discussion-between-screw-spike-and-dt-nguyn).